# Problems importing Three.js FlyControls in a React project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, three.js

I've been struggling trying to get the default flycontrols imported into my React Three.js project.

I've tried importing the FlyControls the following way from their respective folder in the three.js node_modules location:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import FlyControls from "three/examples/js/controls/FlyControls"

// in componentDidMount()
this.controls = new FlyControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
```

This gives me the error `ReferenceError: Three is not defined.` If I try changing the controls assignment line to the following:

```
this.controls = new THREE.FlyControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
```

I get this error: `Attempted import error: 'FlyControls' is not exported from 'three' (imported as 'THREE').`

I've also tried installing the three-fly-controls npm package and not had any luck this route either, this is the code I used in that case:

```
import FlyControls from 'three-fly-controls';

// in componentDidMount()
this.controls = new FlyControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
```

Does anyone know how to get these controls imported correclty?

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used the fly controls but I got the orbit controls to work using the npm package by doing this:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
const OrbitControls = require('three-orbit-controls')(THREE);
```

I then instantiated them in my project like this:

```
this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
```